# I have a SQL Table with employees and a timestamp for their every action. How to calculate how much they worked, and how much they idled (20min gaps)?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a very simple query that looks like this

```
SELECT
    Username
    ,FORMAT(Timestamp, 'MM/dd/yyyy') as Date
    ,FORMAT(Timestamp, 'hh:mm tt') as Time
FROM 
    AuditRecords

ORDER BY
    date desc
    ,Username
    ,Timestamp
```

Here is a sample output of running that query.

| Username | Date | Time |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Employee1 | 05/10/2022 | 12:10 AM |
| Employee1 | 05/10/2022 | 12:23 AM |
| Employee1 | 05/10/2022 | 12:25 AM |
| Employee1 | 05/10/2022 | 12:27 AM |
| Employee1 | 05/10/2022 | 12:28 AM |
| Employee1 | 05/10/2022 | 12:31 AM |
| Employee1 | 05/10/2022 | 12:33 AM |
| Employee1 | 05/10/2022 | 01:43 AM |
| Employee1 | 05/10/2022 | 02:18 AM |
| Employee1 | 05/10/2022 | 03:06 AM |
| Employee1 | 05/10/2022 | 03:20 AM |
| Employee1 | 05/10/2022 | 03:26 AM |
| Employee1 | 05/10/2022 | 04:02 AM |
| Employee1 | 05/10/2022 | 04:05 AM |
| Employee1 | 05/10/2022 | 04:07 AM |
| Employee1 | 05/10/2022 | 04:09 AM |
| Employee1 | 05/10/2022 | 04:14 AM |
| Employee2 | 05/10/2022 | 01:08 AM |
| Employee2 | 05/10/2022 | 01:13 AM |
| Employee2 | 05/10/2022 | 01:15 AM |
| Employee2 | 05/10/2022 | 01:22 AM |
| Employee2 | 05/10/2022 | 01:24 AM |
| Employee2 | 05/10/2022 | 01:28 AM |
| Employee2 | 05/10/2022 | 01:30 AM |
| Employee2 | 05/10/2022 | 01:32 AM |
| Employee2 | 05/10/2022 | 01:57 AM |
| Employee2 | 05/10/2022 | 01:58 AM |
| Employee2 | 05/10/2022 | 04:53 AM |
| Employee3 | 05/10/2022 | 12:50 AM |
| Employee3 | 05/10/2022 | 12:50 AM |
| Employee3 | 05/10/2022 | 12:50 AM |
| Employee3 | 05/10/2022 | 03:00 AM |
| Employee3 | 05/10/2022 | 03:58 AM |
| Employee3 | 05/10/2022 | 04:56 AM |
| Employee3 | 05/10/2022 | 05:42 AM |

Now as you can see, there are three employees.
Employee1 did their first task at 12:10 AM and their last task at 04:14 AM

Originally, what I was doing was taking their first and last action, and just subtracting them to see how many hours they worked.

```
SELECT
    Username
    ,FORMAT(Timestamp, 'MM/dd/yyyy') as Date
    ,FORMAT (min(Timestamp) , 'hh:mm tt') as FirstAction
    ,FORMAT (max(Timestamp) , 'hh:mm tt') as LastAction 
    ,DATEDIFF(hour, min(Timestamp),max(Timestamp)) AS HoursWorked
FROM 
    AuditRecords
GROUP BY
    Username
    ,FORMAT(Timestamp, 'MM/dd/yyyy')
ORDER BY
    date desc
    ,Username
```

So for the case of Employee1, it would return 4 hours. As the difference between 12AM and 4 AM.

However, now we want to calculate this metric in a more sophisticated way.
For example, around the middle of his shift, his actions took place at

01:43 AM, 02:18 AM, 03:06 AM

Which is roughly 40 minutes between each action.
So instead of counting this as working time, I actually want to count this as idle time.

In the beginning of Employee1's shift, he was doing actions every 2-3 minutes. So I want to count this as working time.

However, starting at 12:33 AM to 3:06 AM, since his actions are so spread apart, I want to count this as idle time.

I want to be able to set a custom idle metric. Like 30 or 40 minutes. And if their consecutive actions have more than that metric as a gap, then we count it as being idle.

Is this possible to do with a SQL query? I would have to somehow check each row compared to it's previous one.

So in the end, I want to return a total of working minutes, and a total of idle minutes, per day per employee.

Any help or guidance in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: FYI, `FORMAT` is a *very* expensive operator. If you want the value as a date and time then `CONVERT`/`CAST` the value to a `date` and/or `time`; manage the presentation format in the presentation layer *not* the SQL layer.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I kept going back between FORMAT and CAST since I didn't know which was better. This is good to know

Comment: You can use lead/lag window function